# How to solve: I/O error during "open" operation for file "/home/ubuntu/Firebird4.0/A.fdb"

Tags: ubuntu, firebird

I am trying to connect FDB file with isql.

```
SQL>  connect "14.208.100.213/3050:/home/ubuntu/Firebird4.0/A.fdb " user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
```

After this i got the error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
I/O error during "open" operation for file "/home/ubuntu/Firebird4.0/A.fdb"
-Error while trying to open file
-Permission denied
```

Permission:

-rwxrwx--- 1 firebird firebird 143581183 Jan 21 13:47 A.fdb*

For checking i opened firebird.config and databases.config with nano, but I have no idea what should i change for permission setting. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: As someone commented on your previous question, which you have now deleted, the user running the Firebird server (generally user `firebird`), does not have permission to access your home directory (even if you grant it access to that individual file). You need to put the database in a directory where the firebird user or group has read/write permission, not just on the file itself, and it would need to have `x` permission on all directories from the root up.

Comment: In general, doing this to your own home directory is not a good idea. Put your database in a common directory (e.g. `/var/firebird`, and make sure the firebird user/group has sufficient permissions.

Comment: I am gonna try put the FDB file in different path. /opt/firebird path is good for this? Because there is no firebird under var.

Comment: You can always *create* a directory. I personally wouldn't put it in `/opt/firebird`, as that is (probably) where your Firebird installation itself resides. Don't mix it (but that is just my opinion). That said, I'm more a Windows user myself. I believe that the Ubuntu layout suggests `/var/lib/firebird`.

Comment: I repeat: you must **learn** how file system permissions work.

Comment: I am checking firebird.config, is there any way to change db path for connection? I have added path of FDB files to  DatabaseAccess but it didn't work yet.

Comment: The Firebird config cannot "fix" problems with file system permissions. You must fix the file system permission problem.